# how to convert object type to time type only in python

Tags: python, time, type-conversion, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert **object type** variable to **time type only** using **pd.to_datetime method**

I write this code bellow but the type of the variable is **still object type**.

`data['Start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Start_time'],format= '%H:%M:%S').dt.time`

Please help me i need to convert this column to time column

Answer (score 0):

Check if your time has an extension like AM/PM. If it's without any extension try this

```
df["Time"] =  pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%H:%M:%S")
```